# Julia list all functions provided by a module

Tags: module, package, julia

I'm looking for a Julia function which, when applied to a module name, lists the functions available through the module.

Basically, I don't want to scour through source code and I've noticed that the documentation for many modules usually doesn't have everything.

Comment: Its possible that if a method in a module isn't documented, it isn't meant for external consumption. In a language like Julia, with no way to make things `private` and a we're-all-adults-here philosophy, simply not documenting something is fairly common.

Answer (score 13):

`names` works, mostly:

```
module MyMod
  test() = 3
  foo() = 4
end
names(MyMod, true)
```

gives me

```
4-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :eval
 :test
 :foo
 :MyMod
```

Just need to strip out the module name and `eval`

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the previous answer slightly, the following seems to work:

```
function module_functions(modname)
    list = Symbol[]
    for nm in names(modname)
        typeof(eval(nm)) == Function && push!(list,nm)
    end
    return list
end
```

Example:

```
using PyPlot
module_functions(PyPlot)
```

produces the following output in the REPL:

```
165-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :contourf
 :over
 :xticks
 :ion
 :flag
 :summer
 :stackplot
 :tricontourf
 :minorticks_on
 :gray
 :savefig
 :errorbar
 :box
 :figure
 :vlines
 :subplot_tool
 :jet
 ⋮
 :locator_params
 :imshow
 :pie
 :sci
 :axhline
 :streamplot
 :hist2d
 :copper
 :text3D
 :Axes3D
 :loglog
 :zticks
 :hexbin
 :pcolor
 :semilogy
 :thetagrids
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with Julia 0.5.x.